# texture is on the wrong side of the mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, shaders, normals

I imported a obj and when it came in the texture is on the inside of the mesh. I tried to flip the normals but that didn't work i also tried to recalculate the normals but that didn't work as well. what should i do?                  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6t4gcsslihmgb3z/AACxyD-4BZN_brBs1cIN0keGa?dl=0

Comment: Two similar geometries on top of each other: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8VqP.jpg Split the object by loose part and remove the parts you don't like. *Overlays > Face Orientation* helps to distinguish them. Btw, the prefered way to share your blend here is using: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just figured it out, it took me some time to notice this mistake and I am not even sure how this thing was created.. but look at the top part of your UV:
[image]

Do you see something strange? Look closer to that black spot at the top:
[image]

[image]
If you take that small hidden UV and scale it over the old one:
[image]

For some reason you had 2 UV maps, 1 for inside and 1 for outside, your inside UV was right in a good place but your outside UV was scaled down

Edit: Aha! Your Mesh was duplicated, there were two meshes in one

Are you the one who made this? Or where is this from?
[image]

Comment: no i got it from sketchfab but thanks for figuring this out i was so confused

Comment: You should send message to creator about it, maybe it is some mistake he doesn't know about

Comment: yeah will do and thanks again

Comment: As mentioned in [my comment, the geometries are similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239586/texture-is-on-the-wrong-side-of-the-mesh#comment406345_239586) and not identical, otherwise you could use *Merge by Distance* which fails in this case. I initially thought it is LOD geo, but obviously it's not, slightly rotated for whatever reason.